# Once an animation is rendered, does it become a permanent part of the .blend file, i.e. it is no longer possible to move the camera and rerender?

Tags: rendering

I have rendered a file successfully, but if I go back to that file and try to render either a single image or the entire animation from a different camera position the (F12) render window comes up as a grey/transparent screen and nothing at all is rendered. I have tried clearing all Bakes. I am wondering if I am suppose to make ac opy of the completed file before rendering, so if I want to make several rendered versions from the same file, I would have to make new copy for each new render. Is that correct??

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confused about the basic functionality of the rendering process.

Rendering an image (or sequence) in Blender will either write the file to temporary storage, in which case you have to save it manually, or it will save the image sequence to the folder you have specified in the render settings.

If you are having trouble seeing a render after you hit F12, then make sure you have one of your windows set to "Image Editor" and in the dropdown at the top choose "Render Result".  Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Here is a link to a screen shot of my original animation render, taken from the resulting .mp4 file.  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16khRLrinbQDrVYABT65j8qbTErMFCxrd/view?usp=sharing)  Here is a link to a screen shot of the same .blend file. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1no4JrJ9HV3OWtCQSNiL2BH_SYsSGQ5WC/view?usp=sharing) I have merely pressed the the F12 key. Notice the Image editor opened automatically, and shows the grey/transparency screen and render info at the top, but no image has actually been rendered. How do I get Blender to do additional renders?

Comment: By the way, I have a folders of both successfully completed rendered images, and another full of successfully completed animations, so I doubt that I lack a understanding of the basic functionality, but I do need help trying to understand why successive renders do not appear to  happen 'automatically'

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe I misunderstood what you were saying then. Maybe you have the camera (render) button turned off on some of your assets then?  I will check out the project file when I have time and let you know if I see anything.

Comment: Hey I thought you posted the .blend file but I realize you just posted a screenshot.  I'm happy to take a look at the file if you want to link it.

Comment: Hey Glen, I have added the .blend file for you to take at look at. I am using v. 3.2.1 By the way this problem is true for every file where I have done at least one animated sequence, so I do not think it is a case that I have accidentally changed the render visibility. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10LzyCZxctbv1dPn7-YyS78YVzJdzf3HA?usp=sharing)